# How do I create a bookmark in a pdf with rst2pdf?

Tags: rst2pdf

I need to generate a pdf from a large set of rst files.  Is it possible to generate bookmarks with rst2pdf?  How do I do it?  I am trying to avoid having to do it by hand with Acrobat.

The documentation has headings like 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2...3.4.6, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you use table of contents this is done automatically:

Add:

```
.. contents:: Table of contents
```